# htaccess file run with dash or with underscore both

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my website and I wants something like this:

filename is: apple_banana.php

Now I wants to access this file either with underscore "apple_banana.php" or with dash "apple-banana.php" both way. but filename will stay "apple_banana.php". I don't want 2 files. so how can I do this with htaccess?

I wants this for my whole project files.

thanks,
Aj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(apple)-(banana\.php)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]
```

To make this generic (apply to all the URLs) and for any number of dash:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-+(.*)$ $1_$2 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** as per comments:

```
# To externally redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(apple/apple)_(banana\.php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(apple/apple)-(banana\.php)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot +1.  another small question: I wants also like: if I access "www.abc.com/a_a.php" then it will redirect like "www.abc.com/a-a.php" with above thing which you answered. is that possible?

Comment: You're welcome. In my generic any rule you can just reverse hyphen and dash for that e.g. **`RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L]`**

Comment: Given +1, Yes, what I mean was: I have file apple_banana.php now I wants it to rediret using htaccess to apple-banana.php so when I access apple_banana.php it will show apple-banana.php in URL. And file should run with dash in URL like this apple-banana.php. So how can I do this?

Comment: Some how its not seems to be working. I have this code in my file:    RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(a)-(a\.php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(a)-(a\.php)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]

Comment: Had a typo, try it now.

Comment: going offline for a meeting. WIll be back in an hour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41923/discussion-between-narolainfotech-demo-and-anubhava)

Comment: I am on a mobile now. Leave your comments here and I will attend it as soon as I get back to my computer.

Comment: Redirection is not working still like: if I write this: apple_banana.php in URL then its not redirecting to apple-banana.php using code you have given.

Comment: Actually that should work with rule I gave. Try in a new browser and make sure that 301 rule is before any rules you have.

Comment: I have tried it. still not. here is my file:RewriteEngine On
# To externally redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(apple)_(banana\.php)[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [R=301,L,NE]
# internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^(apple)-(banana\.php)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]

Comment: And I am trying this URL: http://www.app.com/apple/apple_banana.php (however its not redirecting to http://www.app.com/apple/apple-banana.php)

Comment: any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, its throwing 404 error. redirection is working fine but throwing error. The requested URL /apple/apple-banana.php was not found on this server.

Comment: try last rule with a slash: `RewriteRule ^(apple/apple)-(banana\.php)$ /$1_$2 [L,NC]`

Comment: I wants this thing "/apple/apple-banana.php" like this "/apple/apple_banana.php" in "# internal rewrite"

Comment: Can you join the chat with me http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41923/discussion-between-narolainfotech-demo-and-anubhava

Comment: still this like not working: apple.com/apple-a/aaaaa (if first folder has "-" after domain name then its giving error 404) other things are working fine. just needs this resolved. I am writing this in my file "RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-+(.*)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]"

Comment: I am confused because of constantly changing URIs you have. Its better if you print your latest `.htaccess` in your question with all the URIs that you can have and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry my apologize. Here is the correct URL's:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235979/in-htaccess-first-folder-is-not-working-with-dashes

Comment: And I am using only that 2 lines.