# in htaccess first folder is not working with dashes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URL like this: http://example.com/apple_a/

I am using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)-+(.*)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]
```

this is replacing other URL's like http://example.com/apple/a_a/a_b to "http://example.com/apple/a-a/a-b" (underscore with dashes) but when I write "_" in first directory like this "http://example.com/apple-a/a-a/" then its throwing 404 error.

So I wants that working somehow. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct rule will be:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-+(.*)$ $1_$2 [L,NC]
```

You have `([^_]*)` instead of `([^-]*)`

Comment: I am trying this url : http://example.com/apple-a and its throwing 404 with above htaccess rule.

Comment: Hmm I even tried `/apple-a/a-b-c` and it was internally rewritten to `/apple_a/a_b_c`

Comment: right, do you have any idea about fixing this? if yes please tell me.

Comment: If you directly try `http://example.com/apple-a` does it load correct page? (`http://example.com/apple-a` doesn't get affected at all with this rule)

Comment: rest things are working fine. except if "-" will come in first part after domain. if I write like this http://example.com/apple_a/a-a/b-b than also its working fine. but not working with "apple-a".

Comment: well that explains doesn't it. That means rule is working fine but your web server doesn't recognize `http://example.com/apple-a`

Comment: its coming in my local pc and on other 2 pcs too. So I think there is some issues. if you try there then also you will find same. I tried last night in many pcs too.

Comment: Problem is not rewrite rule, problem is your URL scheme. If you directly try `http://example.com/apple-a` it is giving you 404 that problem is not caused by rewrite rule. You can even move away these rules and this 404 will remain

Comment: the issue is not that. let me try to describe here. the issue is only root folder is not accepting dash (-). rest all folders are working fine with dash. So my question is why only root folder is not accesible with dash while its working fine with underscore.

Comment: Sorry sir, Its working fine. my mistake. I was using it from subfloder. +1